I cant import Anko Library on my Android Project
i need a little help here.
(ps i know i need remove the library from the project... but, before that i need build the project)
My problem, on this project someone used Anko library, and this library was discontinued.
I ***found *@aar and @jar , on internet repository , and i have the files already downloaded from a old dev from the team.
So i have files, i have a repository working, but I CANT make AndroidStudio Download this Library.
I tried, and i tried, and i tried. But not work. I need little help here guys.
*The URL from nexus that i found library still active http://maven.xdja.com:8081/nexus3/service/rest/repository/browse/public/org/jetbrains/anko/anko/ added the url on project, and not worked (image atached)* 
Put files on .gradle on repository and enable --offline mode to build (not worked)
If anyone can help i will apreciate.


The link you added as a repository is only for browsing. If we search for anko on this page and click on any of the components it'll show that the actual repository name is aliyun. The link for this repository is available here and it is http://maven.xdja.com:8081/nexus3/repository/aliyun/:
repositories {
    // other repos
    maven {
        url = uri("http://maven.xdja.com:8081/nexus3/repository/aliyun/")
        isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

Alternatively, download all the necessary .aar files, put them in /app/libs/ and include them as a dependency:
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree("libs") { include("*.aar") })


i will try the solution

Not work . The aprouch with libs can find package [xxx.xxx.anko].defaultSharedPreference that is my import... and  the [xxx.xxx.anko] founded! On main class. But when i try search for a class inside aar, any class found, looks somethinh as a blank package, weird.

Maybe you haven't download all the necessary libraries? I tried with anko-commons-0.10.8.aar and commons-base-0.10.8.aar and was able to import org.jetbrains.anko.defaultSharedPreferences. It also worked with a custom maven repository that I added to my answer. @luizfelipetx

I will try again
